# Angular rxjs forkjoin how to use more than 6 parameters

Tags: rxjs, angular7

I am unable to add more than 6 observables to forkjoin. is there a way to use more than 6 parameters?

I am getting error when i try to use it:

```
forkJoin([countries, currencies, customers, shippers, states, types, tradeTypes]).subscribe((results) => {
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 7 Rxjs forkJoin unable to add new Observable to the existing list ie. more than 6 parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60434304/angular-7-rxjs-forkjoin-unable-to-add-new-observable-to-the-existing-list-ie-mo)